# iOS Custom URL Scheme - get source URL

Tags: iphone, ios, webview, url-scheme

I'm working on an app which launches from a custom url scheme.

I've managed to get the url and its parameters and everything, however, our app launches a web view. we want that when the user clicks a link with this scheme, the same page he is on would open up in our web view (it's needed because other functions run in the background, and allowing the user to keep browsing the website he was on)

Is it even possible to get the location of the clicked url? I know I can get the source application, but is there any way (other than adding the link to the scheme itself as parameters) to get the source link?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean impementing the `-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` method in the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol?

Comment: Do you mean getting the URL of the page that the user was on before entering your app?

Comment: Think the only way is to do what you said and add it as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need information passed in to your application, that information must be somehow represented by in URL itself.

Adding a generic interface for that purpose wouldn't make sense as those URLs could be hosted inside an email message or an SMS, for example.